# Angular 11 component is not resolved on Universal SSR Lambda

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, server-side-rendering, angular-components, angular-universal

When using Angular Universal with AWS Lambda Edge, the component cannot be resolved.

```
Error: Component 'AuthComponent' is not resolved:
 - templateUrl: ./auth.component.html
 - styleUrls: ["./auth.component.scss"]
Did you run and wait for 'resolveComponentResources()'?
    at Function.get (/var/task/dist/project/server.js:27891:27)
    at getComponentDef (/var/task/dist/project/server.js:1663:16)
    at verifyDeclarationsHaveDefinitions (/var/task/dist/project/server.js:27574:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (/var/task/dist/project/server.js:27546:18)
    at flatten.map.forEach.mod (/var/task/dist/project/server.js:27543:9)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at verifySemanticsOfNgModuleDef (/var/task/dist/project/server.js:27541:60)
    at flatten.map.forEach.mod (/var/task/dist/project/server.js:27543:9)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

We are running `"build:serverless:deploy"`. Detailed commands are:

```
"build:serverless": "npm run build:browser:serverless && npm run build:server:serverless",
"build:serverless:deploy": "npm run build:serverless && npm run deploy",
"deploy": "serverless deploy",
```

This is our AuthComponent.

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'kt-auth',
    templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./auth.component.scss'],
})
export class AuthComponent {
    today: number = Date.now();
}
```

We are using Angular 11.

Comment: have you find a way to fix this issue? I'm having the same problem with Jest unit tests